# Play fade-in and fade-out in loop

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am a newbie to as3. I have got one movieclip in the scene. I want to play them in loop when my_mc fade-out it must starts to fade in and vice-versa. I want to play them in loop. The fade out function first works fine. But how to load fade-in after fade-out?

```
my_mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fadeout);

function fadeout(e:Event){
    if(my_mc.alpha >=1){
        this.alpha -=0.1;
        if(my_mc.alpha <=0){
            this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fadeout);
        }
    }
}

my_mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fadein);

function fadein(e:Event){
    if(my_mc.alpha <=0){
        this.alpha +=0.1;
        if(my_mc.alpha >=1){
            this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fadein);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my_mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fadeout);

function fadeout(e:Event){
    if(my_mc.alpha <=0){
        my_mc.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fadeout);
        my_mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fadein);
    } else {
        my_mc.alpha -=0.1;
    }
}

function fadein(e:Event){
    if(my_mc.alpha >= 1){
        my_mc.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fadein);
        my_mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fadeout);
    } else {
        my_mc.alpha +=0.1;
    }
}
```

Comment: @sch This is great, really useful, thanks =) HOWEVER, I'm not certain how to improve this even more... How would you program a way to call this function for any MC? I mean, maybe the fadeout/in function can receive a mc parameter. But I'm not certain how to change the addEventListener section. Could he please give some advice?? THANKS =)

Comment: Now I know how to do it, I've answered my own question hehe. I've posted it as a new answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

In `fadeout`, once you have detected the alpha is <= 0 and remove the event listener, just add  another listener for the `fadein` function:

```
function fadeout(e:Event){
    if(my_mc.alpha >=1){
        this.alpha -=0.1;
        if(my_mc.alpha <=0){
            this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fadeout);
            this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fadein);  // add this
        }
    }
}
```

If you want it to loop back and forth repeatedly, you can do something similar to your `fadein` function.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to improve the original @sch answer =)
I've done a function where you can pass any given movieclip as an argument and the Fadein/fadeout cicle will be applied to it. Here's how (with comments):

```
// A boolean variable holds the flag for this to be applied
var boolFadeinFadeoutCicle:Boolean=true;
// This function can receive as a parameter a movieclip
function fncFadeinFadeout(mc:MovieClip){
    if(boolFadeinFadeoutCicle){
        //The fadeout listener it's added here, all relative to the mc received
            MovieClip(mc).addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, Fadeout);
        function Fadeout(evt:Event){
            MovieClip(mc).alpha -=0.05;
                    //Once the mc.alpha reaches zero, the fadeout listener it's removed and the fadein one it's added
            if (MovieClip(mc).alpha <= 0){  
                MovieClip(mc).removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, Fadeout);
                MovieClip(mc).addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, Fadein);
            }
                    //Here the logic it's the same, but inverted.
            function Fadein(evt:Event){
                MovieClip(mc).alpha +=0.05;
                if (MovieClip(mc).alpha >= 1){  
                    MovieClip(mc).removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, Fadein);
                    MovieClip(mc).addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, Fadeout);
                }
            }
        }
    }           
}
```

As you can see, it's the same logic as @sch answer, but with a different structure which can accept a MovieClip as a parameter like this:

```
fncFadeinFadeout(mc0);
fncFadeinFadeout(mc0);
fncFadeinFadeout(mc0);
...
```

All those MovieClips will fade in and out equally.
Thanks to @sch answer and to [this tutorial](http://www.isgoodstuff.com/2008/11/05/actionscript-30-enter-the-frame-eventlistener/)!
I hope you all find this different approach useful ;) =)